# org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException thrown when calling ant from gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am trying to run a specific version of ant inside of a gradle script but I am receiving an exception when the gradle task tries to run ant:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/myuser/DEV/path/to/specific/ant/installation/apache-ant/bin/ant'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

And the code executing ant:

```
def executeAntTaskCmdL(String target, String property, String projectName) {
ext['target'] = target
       ant.cmd = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/$projectsFolder" + "/" + projectName + "/path/to/antInstallation/apache-ant" + File.separator + 'bin' + File.separator + 'ant'

if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        ant.cmd = ant.cmd + '.bat'
    }

    exec {
        commandLine ant.cmd, target, property
    }

}
```

I am not sure what could be causing this exception? Many thanks in advance

Comment: are you on windows?

Comment: Nope, I am using osx.

Comment: and no other output in logs ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. This is the only exception that is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found an error.
I added a build file to my commandLine. Like this:

```
def executeAntTaskCmdL(String target, String property, String projectName) {
ext['buildfile'] = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/$projectsFolder" + "/" + projectName + "/path/to/buildFile" + File.separator + 'build.xml'
ext['target'] = target
       ant.cmd = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/$projectsFolder" + "/" + projectName + "/path/to/antInstallation/apache-ant" + File.separator + 'bin' + File.separator + 'ant'

if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        ant.cmd = ant.cmd + '.bat'
    }

    exec {
        commandLine ant.cmd, target, '-buildfile', buildfile, property
    }

}
```

After adding this everything runs like a charm.